# nanoKONTROL2 receive/send data RtMidi c++

Tags: c++, midi

**Two Questions:**
**1)** Is it possible to send a message to the device and receive all the current input values?

I am trying to receive and send data to the KORG nanoKONTROL2. I found an API for real-time input/output called [RtMidi](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/). Receiving data is no issue, but I don't have the state where the sliders and knobs are in when the application starts. I presume, if this could be done, you need to send a message to the device.

There is an `RtMidiOut` class with `sendMessage` functionality where you can send data (`vector<uchar>`) to the device, but I don't know what data to send (I did try with some for loops to see if anything happens, but no luck).

**2)** Is it possible to turn the button lights on/off? If so, how?

To clarify the second question; I am trying to create a toggle where the light of the button on the device will turn on/off according to the state of the toggle.

**Additional Information:**
 The received data exists of 3 `unsigned char`'s where the first value is probably an id, I am not quite sure, the second is the button/slider id and the third is its value.

[Source code link to GitHub](https://github.com/hoekkii/nanoKONTROL2/tree/develop/nanoKONTROL2/nanoKONTROL2).

Comment: what's the origin of that code you've put on Github?

Comment: and have you seen this?   http://www.korg.com/us/support/download/manual/0/159/2710/

Comment: @Alnitak What do you mean with the origin? The code on GitHub I wrote myself except for the RtMidi. Thank you for the link, I previously did not see that. I got the LEDs working now. You have to set the LED mode in the "Korg Kontrol Editor" to "External". To control the led you need to send `{ 0xB0, <button ID>, <on: 0xF7, off: 0x00>}` to the device.

Comment: it was hard to see where the RtMidi code ended and yours began.    That hex sequence can't be right, BTW - `0xf7` is the byte for the _end_ of a SysEx sequence.  It's most likely supposed to be `0x7f`.   `0xb0 cc vv` is the standard MIDI sequence for "on MIDI channel 1 set the control identified by `cc` to the value `vv`".    `cc` and `vv` cannot exceed 127 (0x7f)

Comment: Typo, Sorry.. `{ 0xB0, <button ID>, <on: 0x7F, off: 0x00>}`

Comment: The question is whether the nanoKONTROL2 has commands for that. [Apparently not](https://medias.audiofanzine.com/files/nanokontrol2-midiimp-478714.txt).